# In a multi-user environment, where is Adobe Bridge Metadata stored?

Tags: nas, dropbox, metadata, adobe-bridge

I have a team of designers / non-technical users that want to start using Adobe Bridge as an asset management & tagging system (lets say 8 people) this will be photos (edited and RAW), videos (again edited, project files and as-shot), and other assets such as large .INDD .AI .PSD files etc.

As is a common thing now, the working arrangements are varied, several offices, some will be working from home on occasion. Currently most users will download a project folder (if large), work on it locally then re-upload.

So my question is around how AB stores it's Metadata, the files will be on a NAS at the office that also syncs to Dropbox, each client will have AB installed locally on both PC and Mac.

How does AB actually store its metadata, is it embedded in each file (which I can imagine will be hellishly slow for search purposes when working remotely), in a central database file, or locally per client? (or a hybrid thereof)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### How does AB actually store its metadata?

It's stored in the file itself, or in a separate "sidecar" file:

> Metadata information is stored using the Extensible Metadata Platform (XMP) standard, on which Adobe Bridge, Adobe Illustrator, Adobe InDesign, and Adobe Photoshop are built. Adjustments made to images with Photoshop Camera Raw are stored as XMP metadata. XMP is built on XML, and in most cases the metadata is stored in the file. If it isn’t possible to store the information in the file, metadata is stored in a separate file called a sidecar file.

Source: [Learn about Extensible Metadata Platform (XMP) standard and working with metadata in Adobe Bridge](https://helpx.adobe.com/bridge/using/metadata-adobe-bridge.html)

---

#### So what is a "sidecar" file?

Sidecar files are created when editing raw images:

> Metadata updates are not applied to the original raw capture by software such as Adobe Bridge, Photoshop, or Lightroom Classic. Therefore, if you lost an XMP sidecar file (and your catalog in the case of Lightroom Classic) you would lose the metadata updates and adjustments for that photo.
>
> When you apply metadata updates or adjustments to a raw capture, those updates are not actually written to the source raw capture. The idea is that the raw capture represents the original unprocessed image, and you don’t want to risk corrupting that file by making changes to it.
>
> Instead of updating the source raw capture, updates are written elsewhere. In Lightroom Classic by default any updates you apply are only saved within the Lightroom Classic catalog. Other software such as Adobe Bridge or Photoshop will write those changes to an XMP sidecar file automatically. And in Lightroom Classic you can enable an option to automatically write updates to an XMP sidecar file (in addition to the catalog) in the Catalog Settings dialog.
>
> Note, by the way, that the XMP sidecar file is a file with the same base filename as the original raw capture, located in the same folder, but with an “xmp” filename extension rather than the extension used by the raw capture format for your camera.

Source: [Importance of XMP Sidecars – Ask Tim Grey](https://asktimgrey.com/2021/05/10/importance-of-xmp-sidecars/)